# How can I count from different tables in Power Pivot?

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerpivot

The data are saved in many spread sheets:

Table A

```
Product    Test_Date    Test_Result
A          2020-05-05   1.06
A          2020-06-01   1.04 
A          2020-06-03
```

Table B

```
Product    Test_Date    Test_Result    Test_Result_2
B          2020-05-04   1.11           2.03
```

Table C

```
Product    Test_Date    Test_Result    Test_Result_2    Test_Result_3
C          2020-05-06   
C          2020-06-04   1.48           2.56             3.32
```

I am trying to create a power pivot showing the statistics of all the products like below. The links between the stas sheet and each product sheet have been established. How can I count from different table for each row?

Table All_Products

```
Product    Test_Count    Result_Mean    Result_Missing
A          3             1.05           1
B          1             1.11           0
C          2             1.48           3
```

I tried to add a new column with this formula and it shows error:

```
=COUNTROWS(RELATEDTABLE(All_Products[Product]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Power Query](https://powerquery.microsoft.com/en-us/excel/) to [Append Queries](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/append-queries-power-query-e42ca582-4f62-4a43-b37f-99e2b2a4813a) so the three ranges load into a single Power Pivot table.